# Placing an "Image" outside of a div, Example inside my post

Tags: html, css

Okay, let's see if I can explain what I mean, here's an image to help:

[image: Example]

So as you can see in the image, I need to get the green arrow from its current location to being placed outside the main div that holds it. I need so if the page is re-sized the arrow will stay in its position. 
If you need any more information, please let me know. Sorry if this is too vague, I wasn't sure how to explain it. 
Thanks!

Comment: you can accomplish this with absolute positioning http://css-tricks.com/791-absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/
seems to have some good examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the container element `position: relative;` and then give the arrow `position: absolute; top: 0; right: -x;` (where x is the width of the arrow).

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/joshnh/xpFPd/

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply absolute positioning. If it will always be a constant distance from the left or right then this is easy.

```
img.class {
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
}
```

For example.

Comment: @joshuanhibbert's solution is similar but likely a better way for your example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative-absolute positioning.

```
Outer_div{
position: relative;
.
.
.
}

img.inner{
position: absolute;
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use relative positioning:

```
parent {
  position: relative;
}

parent img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

This will attach each `img` to the left edge of its parent.